# GWT FlowPanel not showing contents

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt

I'm new to GWT.  I want a VerticalSplitPanel on the left and a VerticalSplitPanel on the right, inside a FlowPanel.  This so that the one on the right moves under the one on the left when the size changes from a desktop to a phone.  But nothing shows up at all, except for a TabPanel that I've placed above the FlowPanel.  Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="tabPanel"></div>
<div id="flowPanel"></div>
```

Here is the java GWT:

```
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    //create TabPanel
    final TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();
    tabPanel.add(new HTML("Add Watchlist Here"),"Watchlists");
    tabPanel.add(new HTML("Add Strategies Here"),"Strategies");
    tabPanel.add(new HTML("Add Backtests Here"),"Backtests");
    tabPanel.selectTab(0);
    RootPanel.get("tabPanel").add(tabPanel);
    
    //create FlowPanel for responsive design to work on small screens
    final FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
    
    //create the left VerticalSplitPanel
    final VerticalSplitPanel leftVerticalSplitPanel = new VerticalSplitPanel();
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.setSize("300px", "500px");
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.setSplitPosition("35%");
            
    //add dummy TextArea to left top VerticalSplitPanel
    TextArea leftTextAreaTop = new TextArea();
    leftTextAreaTop.setVisibleLines(5);
    leftTextAreaTop.setText("dummy text to show left top widget");
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.setTopWidget(leftTextAreaTop);

    //add notes TextArea to left bottom VerticalSplitPanel
    TextArea leftTextAreaBottom = new TextArea();
    leftTextAreaBottom.setVisibleLines(5);
    leftTextAreaBottom.setText("dummy text to show left bottom widget");
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.setBottomWidget(leftTextAreaBottom);

    //add the left VerticalSplitPanel to the FlowPanel
    flowPanel.add(leftVerticalSplitPanel);
    
    //create the right VerticalSplitPanel
    final VerticalSplitPanel rightVerticalSplitPanel = new VerticalSplitPanel();
    rightVerticalSplitPanel.setSize("300px", "500px");
    rightVerticalSplitPanel.setSplitPosition("35%");
    
    //add dummy TextArea to right top VerticalSplitPanel
    TextArea rightTextAreaTop = new TextArea();
    rightTextAreaTop.setVisibleLines(5);
    rightTextAreaTop.setText("dummy text to show right top widget");
    rightVerticalSplitPanel.setTopWidget(rightTextAreaTop);

    //add notes TextArea to right bottom VerticalSplitPanel
    TextArea rightTextAreaBottom = new TextArea();
    rightTextAreaBottom.setVisibleLines(5);
    rightTextAreaBottom.setText("dummy text to show right bottom widget");
    rightVerticalSplitPanel.setBottomWidget(rightTextAreaBottom);
      
    //add the right VerticalSplitPanel to the FlowPanel
    flowPanel.add(rightVerticalSplitPanel);
    
    //add the FlowPanel to the RootPanel
    RootPanel.get("flowPanel").add(flowPanel);
  }
```

Note: I throw in a couple of TextAreas in the left VerticalSplitPanel hoping that will make something show up, but no joy.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I fixed one bug and set a size to the two vertical panels.  Now some of them show up but in a strange order.  Left top widget is correct.  Left bottom widget is missing. Right bottom widget is *underneath* the left top widget.  right top widget is `underneath` that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few issues in your code. Starting from the less important:

1. `rightVerticalSplitPanel` is empty, so it will not be visible
2. `leftVerticalSplitPanel` has only bottom widget because you call `setBottomWidget` twice (I guess that there should be `setTopWidget` for `textAreaTop`)
3. You need to set the height of `leftVerticalSplitPanel` (and `rightVerticalSplitPanel`), for example `leftVerticalSplitPanel.setHeight("100px");`
4. `VerticalSplitPanel` is deprecated and will only work in quirks mode, you should use [SplitLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SplitLayoutPanel.html) instead

Comment: 1.  Ok.  2. Fixed that.  See edited code in post.  3. I set size and now I can see them, but in a very strange way.  See comment at end of post.  4.  I'll try that.  Thank you!

Comment: I changed to SplitLayoutPanel as you suggested.  Now all 4 sections are showing correctly but the right SplitLayoutPanel is below the left one, instead of to the right of it.  And there are 2 dividers between the top and bottom instead of 1.

Comment: `VerticalSplitPanel`s are rendered as HTML `div` elements and `div`s are [Block-level Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) (a block-level element always starts on a new line). So it will not work as expected in `FlowPanel`.

Comment: Should I wrap in something to make it work as expected?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in responsive layouts. You can try to change the `display` to `inline-block`: `leftVerticalSplitPanel.getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.INLINE_BLOCK);` (and the same for right panel).

Comment: Good suggestion.  Unfortunately, it still looks the same.  I'll do some experimenting with wrappers.

Comment: Actually, it did work!  I had a typo.  I will accept your answer.  Thank you Adam!  Now if I could only figure out why there are two dividers between the top and bottom sections.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, the reason I was seeing two dividers is because I was using .addNorth and .addSouth.  I should have used .add to the bottom, instead of .addSouth, so it could adjust its height based on the north divider.